# 2D optimize() in R

Tags: r, optimization, 2d

I would like to use optimize() to find parameters of 2 dimensional mixed normal distribution but I don't know how to use the function.

I have the density function:

```
mixdnorm2<-function(x,y,p,mu11,mu12,s11,s12,rho1,mu21,mu22,s21,s22,rho2){

dnorm2<-function(x,y,m1,m2,s1,s2,r){
U<-c(x-m1,y-m2)
S<-matrix(c(s1^2,s1*s2*r,s1*s2*r,s2^2),2,2,byrow = T)
f<-1/(2*pi*sqrt(det(S)))*exp(-0.5%*%t(U)%*%solve(S)%*%U)
return(f)
}

f<-p*dnorm2(x,y,m11,m12,s11,s12,rho1)+(1-p)*dnorm2(x,y,m21,m22,s21,s22,rho2)
return(f)
}
```

but I don't know what to do with it.

```
optimize(mixdnorm2...)
```

Please do you know, how to use the function? I couldn't find anything about the problem so I'll glad for any advice :)

Answer (score 1):

The `optimize` function is only for 1 dimension.  The `optim` function is the one to use for 2 or more dimensions.  So look up the help page for `optim`.

For some reason the help page for `optimize` does not mention `optim`, though the help page for `optim` does mention `optimize`.

There are also some packages that provide additional optimization functions (search on CRAN).

Comment: Hmmm, but I was told to use optimize(), that it should work. Isn't there really a possibility how it can be apply?

Comment: @Bee, who told you to use `optimize`?  Maybe they can give you more direction on what them meant (or confirm that you should use `optim`).  The title on the help page for `optimize` has "One Dimensional" in big letters right at the top, so I don't see any simple way to get it to work on higher dimensions, and the `optim` tool that is designed for higher dimensions seems *optimal* (and your problem is actually more than 2 dimensions in the parameter space).

Comment: It's a part of project/homework, so there was only what I've already written. I thought it would not be that hard, but now I see I might ask for better direction :D Thank you anyway :)